# ROS Answers SE migration: Odom and IMU

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am really beating my head hard over this, excuse me while I ask a silly question.

I'm building my own robot using HCSR04 as range sensors and a MPU925 as an IMU, while going through the navigation package, I got really confused with the difference between data/imu and nav_msg/Odometry. How are the related and what do I need to go to get localization working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275321/odom-and-imu/) by [AllanXyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32465/allanxyl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-11-08**:
Can you be more specific? What does confuse you? And what does the range sensor have to do with odometry in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you connecting your IMU to your *roscore* ?
There is github with relevant code if you are using a raspberry/beaglebone:
https://github.com/vmayoral/bb_mpu9150

If you are using an arduino, then use rosserial and get the data with ROS from there:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0